# LEGO Friends set identification from sealed bag

Tags: set-identification, friends

I have the unopened bags of a LEGO Friends set, but I can't find any number to identify the set.

[image: photo of bag]

Answer (score 4):

This bag is from [3315 - Olivia's House](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3315-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D).

[image]

The instructions for this set can be found [here on the LEGO Customer Service Site](https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&text=3315%2520Olivia%27s%2520House%2520LEGO%2520Friends).